# How to use the line titlePanel.setLayout(null)

Tags: java, netbeans

I need to set the  location of a button anywhere in JFrame, but when i use "titlePanel.setLayout(null)" everything disappears :(

please :)

here it is Jamal H :)

public void addComponentsAndListeners() {

```
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.getContentPane().add(p1);
    p1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 600));
    p1.add(cb1);
    cb1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(180, 30));
    p1.add(b1);
    //b1.setBounds(100,200,100,200);
    pack();
    validate();
```

}

Comment: Post the code please. Are you calling setBounds on your buttons?

Comment: okay. yes, i want to set b1 location

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the Layout with FlowLayout (it is the default Layout) or BorderLayout (North, South, West, East) or GridLayout

Comment: Is it what you want ?